# How do I triage errors from the AppStore? Where are the log files?

Tags: mac-appstore, error, macos

Am getting an error message when trying to reinstall TextWrangler from the App Store. The message given is `An unknown error occurred`. This is not terribly helpful. Where can I look to get more information about this error? Does the App Store application have a log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. You can view it in Applications > Utilties > Console.

Comment: Thats a convenient tool. However I am not seeing any error messages related to the AppStore under "All Messages". Where should I look for AppStore errors?

Comment: All errors are supposed to go there. I mean ALL errors. You should find the error in All Messages. Perhaps it’s under a different process name.

Comment: install.log seems to have some chatter from AppStore, but it does not show the errors.

Comment: There are many processes associated with App Store. Check `accountsd`, `securityd`, `storeagent` and of course, `App Store`.

Comment: Accepted. This didn't show logs for my specific problem, but it was clearly the right place to start triaging and looking for error messages.

Comment: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 6):

You have to enable debugging first before logs show up in the console.

> To activate the Debug menu, open the OS X Terminal utility and run the following command:
>
> ```
> defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
> ```
>
> - Debug Logging options
>
>   The App Store has various levels of debug logging that can be used, which simply increase the verbosity of the store's logging functions and output more information as the log level is increased. If you are finding the store to be unresponsive or behaving oddly, then you can increase the log level and try your actions again to hopefully capture a cause for the problem in the App Store's log file. This file can be accessed by opening the Console utility and then opening the section called "~/Library/Logs" in the Files section of the sidebar.
>
>   The file should be called "appstore.log." The standard debugging levels will log the program's functions such as which URLs it is connecting to and what tasks it is running, but in addition if you are seeing visual or behavioral oddities on various product pages you can enable JavaScript logging to see if any JavaScript-based errors are contributing factors in these problems.

http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57538104-263/make-use-of-the-mac-app-store-debug-menu/

Answer (score 3):

You can see the macOS install logs by executing the following command in the terminal:

```
tail -f /var/log/install.log
```